# angularjs get values after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am creating a angularjs application and the application is something about when user enter a customer id then the result will be shown with all the values

By default application would look like this

[image]

After entring id in user id box mobile will show the result with values according to the user id

[image]

I am able to change the div on button click with angular `ng-show` but later when i will get the values from API i need to know how to load that div with values after button click.

**Problem facing now**

There is a `bxslider` plugin for top slider but when i load the div after button click bxslider doesn't come with height i need to resize the window then only `bxslider` gets visible.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobile_app" ng-controller="mobileViewCtrl">
    <div class="mobile_app_inner" ng-hide="showScreen">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="default_logo">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile_app_inner" ng-scrollbars ng-show="showScreen">
        <div class="banner_section" ng-model="bannerSlider" bx-slider realign="showScreen">
            <div class="slide" ng-repeat="banner in mobileBanner track by $index">
                <img ng-src="images/{{banner}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="category_section clearfix">
            <div class="col-xs-3 category_box" ng-repeat="cate in categories track by $index">
                <a href="#">
                    <img ng-src="images/{{cate.image}}">
                    <p>{{cate.name}}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="smart_message">
            <p>Get 150 Crowns on your referral's 1st check-in with Min. Bill of Rs. 100. Valid Till 15-Aug.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mission_outer_box">
            <div class="mission_box clearfix" ng-repeat="mission in missions">
                <img src="images/tick_patch.png" class="expired_img" ng-show="{{mission.status=='Completed'}}">
                <h2>{{mission.name}}</h2>
                <p class="clearfix"><em>Win</em> <span><img src="images/crown.png"> {{mission.crownwin}} Crowns</span> <span><img src="images/voucher.png"> {{mission.voucherwin}} Voucher</span></p>
                <div class="progress_box_outer clearfix">
                    <div class="progress_box">
                        <span style="width:{{100/mission.tasktotal*mission.taskdone}}%"></span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="progress_count">{{mission.taskdone}}/{{mission.tasktotal}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="expiry_date">
                    <p>{{mission.status}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
.controller('mobileViewCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.mobileBanner = ['banner_small.png', 'banner_small.png', 'banner_small.png'];
    $scope.categories = [
        {'image':'category1.png','name':'Bill Payment'},
        {'image':'category2.png','name':'Doctors'},
        {'image':'category3.png','name':'Events'},
        {'image':'category4.png','name':'Movies'},
        {'image':'category5.png','name':'Gym'},
        {'image':'category6.png','name':'Hotels'},
    ];
    $scope.missions = [
        {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'5','taskdone':'4','status':'Expire on 25/06'},
        {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'4','taskdone':'2','status':'Completed'},
        {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'4','taskdone':'2','status':'Expired'}
    ];
})
```